# Правильно ли я понял абстрактную фабрику?

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, подскажите, являются мои ли каляки реализацией паттерна "абстрактная фабрика"? Правильно ли я его понял? Спасибо

```
<?php

/*
 * Цветы
 */
interface IFlower{
    function getColor();
    function smell();
}

abstract class AFlower implements IFlower{
    abstract function getColor();
    abstract function smell();
}

class Rose extends AFlower{
    function getColor(){
        return "red";
    }

    function smell(){
        return "smell of roses";
    }
}

class Violet extends AFlower{
    function getColor(){
        return "blue";
    }

    function smell(){
        return "smell of violets";
    }
}

/*
 * Фабрики
 */
interface IFactory{
    function getFlower();
}

abstract class AbstractFactory implements IFactory{
    abstract function getFlower();
}

class RosesFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    function getFlower(){
        return new Rose();
    }
}

class VioletsFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    function getFlower(){
        return new Violet();
    }
}

function getMeFlower(IFactory $factory){
    if (!isset($factory)){
        return false;
    }
    return $factory->getFlower();
}

$i = random_int(1, 2);

switch ($i){
    case 1:
        $factory = new RosesFactory();
        break;
    case 2:
        $factory = new VioletsFactory();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("This can not be!");
}

$flower = getMeFlower($factory);
echo $flower->getColor();
```

Comment: Смысл любой из фабрик — это создание объектов, а не примитивов и вам, для понимания, лучше переоформить вопрос с объектами.

Comment: @user3127286, спасибо, стало быть, что уже точно не зря вопрос задал :)

Comment: @user3127286, пожалуйста, взгляните, если не затруднит: как насчет теперь?

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясню на вашем примере.

Сами по себе `RosesFactory` и `VioletsFactory` в таком виде не показывают преимуществ абстрактной фабрики.

Приведу цитату из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

> Абстрактная фабрика (англ. Abstract factory) — порождающий шаблон проектирования, предоставляет интерфейс для создания **семейств взаимосвязанных или взаимозависимых объектов**, не специфицируя их конкретных классов.

То есть вам нужны интерфейсы:

`IFlower` и `IFlowerPaper` - взаимосвязанные объекты необходимые для букета

```
interface IBouqet {
    public function getFlower(); 
    public function getPaper();
}
```

Букет может быть с бумагой или без, с разными цветами. (Возьмем за правило что разных цветов в букете не будет).

Покупатель захочет получить букет с **определенной бумагой** определяемой узором и цветом (по-этому это объект реализующий `IFlowerPaper`) и с определенными цветами (`IFlower`)

Наша абстрактная фабрика `IBouqet` служит для описания интерфейса букета для клиента.

В нашем магазине цветов есть конечное количество вариаций букетов. Классы-наследники `IBouqet` будут конкретными фабриками.

Например `RosesBouqetFactory` или `VioletsBouqetFactory` будут создавать конкретные букеты из конкретных составляющих. Розы могут быть разных сортов `IRoses` и фиалки `IViolets`,  так-же им нужна бумага `iFlowerPaper`.

Покупатель выбирает розы красные, в такой-то упаковке или без неё.

— "Дайте мне красных роз в прозрачной упаковке тысяч за 5"

---

Или он выбирает просто цветы на выбор продавца (Абстрактной фабрики. Если эта абстрактная фабрика может создавать своего конкретного потомка например основываясь, например, на диапазоне цен и/или цвете).

— "Дайте мне симпатичный букетик тысяч за 5"

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь и разъяснения!